# Unable to create Controller in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create a controller in Visual Studio using Scaffolding.
I am not sure what is wrong here. I keep getting this error. I even repaired my entire application. No Luck.

[image]

More details,

Happening with other nuget Packages too.

Failed to download package 'dotnet-reportgenerator-cli.4.0.2' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/dotnet-reportgenerator-cli/4.0.2/dotnet-reportgenerator-cli.4.0.2.nupkg'.
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).

Comment: Do you have a company proxy server that forbids access to the NuGet API?

Comment: I will have to check that, looks like same happens if I use my home network

Comment: Thanks You were right. The have had Zscalar Client, which blocks all nuget packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 403 indicates that either NuGet itself, or an intermediary is refusing the request.

If the former, the problem should be solved by NuGet itself quite soon, as hundreds of thousands of developers worldwide rely on it.

If it persist, chances are there's a proxy server on your machine or network blocking the request. Ensure that is the case, and if so, take the necessary steps to get NuGet whitelisted in that proxy.